# Display charging status *and* percentage in panel

Tags: kde-plasma-5

By default, the "Battery and Brightness" icon displays the charging status, i.e. whether the battery is charging, discharging or neither. You can configure it to display the percentage (right click -> Configure Battery and Brightness... -> Show percentage) but then the percentage covers the in a way that hides the status. How to display both?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the panel -> Add widgets... -> Add two instances of the Battery and Brightness widget side by side. Set one to display the percentage, leave the other alone. Then disable the original icon (right click the tray, e.g. the up icon on the right edge -> Configure System Tray... -> Set the visibility of Battery and Brightness to "Disabled".

This takes up a bit more space, an alternative icon set might allow displaying both pieces of information in once icon.